# How to stop automatic refreshing of WebView in Android

Tags: android, webview

Iam using WebView in my application which loads a remote url.It is able to load the remote url successfully.But whenever i trying to switch my application between background to foreground,sometimes my Current Activity which contains the WebView is refreshing.How to i avoid refreshing of my WebView when i switch from background to foreground.Iam not at all using onResume() in my Activity.May app version is 2.2.My Activity tag in AndroidManifest.xml file is as follows.

```
    <activity 
        android:name=".Main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configchanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|locale|uiMode|mcc|mnc|touchscreen|keyboard">
    </activity>
```

Thanks&Regards,
 Venkat.

Answer (score 2):

Try to override WebViewClient, something like:

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    private boolean alreadyLoaded = false;  
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                if (alreadyLoaded)
                   return;
                alreadyLoaded = true;
                super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

        }


        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add android:launchMode="singleTask" to main activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the state of the webview and restore it in `onCreate` when `savedInstanceState != null`. 
The webview has a function `saveState(..)` which you can use to save the state in the `onSaveInstanceState(..)` of the Activity.

In your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}
```