# Android ProgressTracker Webview Constantly Refreshing, and I need it to stop

Tags: android, android-webview, progress

Hopefully this is an easy one, I'm having this issue where some sort of process spawned by mine, called "ProgressTracker" is causing my webview to constantly refresh at like a 2-3 minute internal. I'm trying to make a static menu board, so the page constantly refreshing is making me go crazy. When I was running the code from Eclipse on my device through the ADT this did not occur, but when I integrated it into the firmware file it does...

Is there just a simple setting where I can disable this annoying bug?

`F/Debug   (  871): CurTS: 1401976422 OldTS: 1401976422
F/Debug   (  871): Json: true
F/Debug   (  871): State=1
F/Debug   (  871): CurTS: 1401976422 OldTS: 1401976422
F/Debug   (  871): Json: true
F/Debug   (  871): State=1
F/Debug   (  871): CurTS: 1401976422 OldTS: 1401976422
F/Debug   (  871): Json: true
F/Debug   (  871): State=1
F/Debug   (  871): CurTS: 1401976422 OldTS: 1401976422
F/Debug   (  871): Json: true
D/ProgressTracker(  871): Progress incremented (0x41b13918) - value 0.884891, tracked frames 1
F/Debug   (  871): State=1
F/Debug   (  871): CurTS: 1401976422 OldTS: 1401976422
F/Debug   (  871): Json: true
F/Debug   (  871): State=1
F/Debug   (  871): CurTS: 1401976422 OldTS: 1401976422
F/Debug   (  871): Json: true
F/Debug   (  871): State=1
F/Debug   (  871): CurTS: 1401976422 OldTS: 1401976422`

Webview configuration:

```
/** Configure WebView */
webview0 = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
webview0.setWebViewClient(new WebViewer());
webview0.getSettings().setUserAgentString("-1");
webview0.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview0.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview0.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview0.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview0.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webview0.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
// webview0.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
webview0.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webview0.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webview0.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
webview0.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
```

WebViewClient:

```
public class WebViewer extends WebViewClient {
private boolean alreadyLoaded = false;

@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    if (alreadyLoaded)
        return;
    alreadyLoaded = true;
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()");
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post your current code ?

Comment: I can post my WebViewClient and WebView configuration?

Comment: This might be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10838605/how-to-stop-automatic-refreshing-of-webview-in-android

Comment: Already implemented in onPageStarted... as shown above. Maybe the onreceiver error does something?

Comment: the code above doesn't seem relevant to your problem. Either your "ProgressTracker" is wrong and is calling .reload/loadUrl on the WebView or there is some JavaScript on the page trying to navigate it (to an ad, maybe?)